# Keyboard shortcut to clear the cmd and windows-terminal

Tags: windows, cmd, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-terminal

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut for the "cls" command under windows as for the terminal on mac with:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>K</kbd>

<kbd>Command</kbd>  +  <kbd>K</kbd>  for newer keyboards

Someone would have any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no keyboard shortcut dedicated to the "cls" command.
However, you can create it yourself as follows: (you can see the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/RashidLadj/7ba22f61ff8c4845849f4fc031e87f8d)

1. you must first download the tool [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com)
2. Install it
3. Create an empty file with the extension ".ahk"
4. Fill the script with the following code to have the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>k</kbd>  (You can choose the shortcut that suits you):

**Script**

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^K::
Send cls{Enter}
return
```

5. Save and run the file by double clicking

***Note***:

This shortcut is no longer valid as soon as you close the current session, so I recommend that you move the file to a special folder which will run the script each time you start windows, here are the steps:

1. Copy the script file
2. Type  <kbd>Windows key</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd>
3. Execute `shell:startup`
4. Paste the file

Comment: In recente versions of Wndows Terminal, you can go to Settings -> Actions and add New action. Select Clear Buffer and assign Ctrl+K! Easy peasy!